# How to set paint effects programmaticaly

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, c++

In my plugin I want to set up a 'halo'-effect like this:
[image]

So far I tried this:

setting up the paint effect:

```
    QgsPaintEffect * p_mPaintEffect(0);
    p_mPaintEffect= new QgsOuterGlowEffect();

    (static_cast<QgsGlowEffect*>(p_mPaintEffect))->setSpreadUnit(QgsSymbolV2::OutputUnit::MapUnit);                  
    (static_cast<QgsGlowEffect*>(p_mPaintEffect))->setSpread(2.0);                      
    (static_cast<QgsGlowEffect*>(p_mPaintEffect))->setBlurLevel(1);
```

assign it with the symbollayer:

```
p_Symbol->symbolLayer(i)->setPaintEffect(p_mPaintEffect);
```

After opening the layer properties dialog there is only one painteffect not like in the image above a list of 5. But I don't know how to set more effects. Where can I get the list? In [API](http://qgis.org/api/2.14/classQgsSymbolLayerV2.html#a5d4f3921ee369094736f17ec44361620) is only documented to set one effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question. After browsing the API I found the solution is to cast the **QgsPaintEffect** to **QgsEffectStack** and edit the existing effects, maybe someone can benefit from this code:

```
    QgsPaintEffect* oldEffect=p_Symbol->symbolLayer(0)->paintEffect();
    QgsEffectStack* stackEffect=(static_cast<QgsEffectStack*>(oldEffect));

    for(int j=0; j< stackEffect->count();j++)
    {
        if (stackEffect->effect(j)->type()=="outerGlow" )
            stackEffect->changeEffect (j,effect);
        else if (stackEffect->effect(j)->type()=="drawSource" )
            stackEffect->effect(j)->setDrawMode(QgsPaintEffect::DrawMode::Render);
    }
    stackEffect->setEnabled(true);
```